# Query which outputs the number of athletes that voted for someone in the same athletePosition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Like the title says, SQL query which outputs the number of athletes that voted for someone in the same athletePosition as himself.

I have 4 tables in my database right now, they consist of:

```
CREATE TABLE award(
    awardId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    awardName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    awardSponsor VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT pk_award_awardId PRIMARY KEY (awardId)
);   

CREATE TABLE winner(
    winnerId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    winnerYear INT NOT NULL,
    athleteId INT NOT NULL,
    awardId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_winner_winnerId PRIMARY KEY (winnerId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_winner_athlete FOREIGN KEY (athleteId) REFERENCES athlete (athleteId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_winner_award FOREIGN KEY (awardId) REFERENCES award (awardId)
);

CREATE TABLE athlete(
    athleteId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    athleteFirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    athleteLastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    athleteDateOfBirth DATE,
    athleteHeight SMALLINT,
    athleteWeight TINYINT,
    athletePosition CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    athleteBattingAvg DECIMAL(4, 3) DEFAULT 0.000,
    athleteNationality VARCHAR(30),
    teamId INT NOT NULL,
    votesForId INT,
    CONSTRAINT pk_athlete_athleteId PRIMARY KEY (athleteId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_athlete_team FOREIGN KEY(teamId) REFERENCES team (teamId),
);

CREATE TABLE team(
    teamId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    teamName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    teamCity VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    teamState CHAR(2),
    teamCountry VARCHAR(6),
    teamManager VARCHAR(50),
    teamLeague CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    teamStadium VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_team_teamId PRIMARY KEY (teamId)
);
```

Here is some sample data for `ATHLETE` Table.

```
    INSERT INTO athlete
VALUES
    ('Vladimir', 'Guererro Jr.', '1999-03-16', 188, 113, '3B', 0.272, 'Canada', 1),
    ('Bo', 'Bichette', '1998-03-05', 183, 83, 'SS', 0.311, 'USA', 1),
    ('Cavan', 'Biggio', '1995-04-11', 188, 90, '2B', 0.234, 'USA', 1),
    ('Travis', 'Shaw', '1990-04-16', 193, 104, '1B', 0.157, 'USA', 1),
    ('Danny', 'Jansen', '1995-04-15', 188, 104, 'C', 0.207, 'USA', 1),
    ('Randal', 'Grichuk', '1991-08-13', 188, 96, 'OF', 0.232, 'USA', 1),
    ('Teoscar', 'Hernandez', '1992-10-15', 188, 92, 'OF', 0.230, 'Dominican Republic', 1),
    ('Tim', 'Anderson', '1993-06-23', 185, 83, 'SS', 0.335, 'USA', 2),
    ('Jose', 'Abreu', '1987-01-29', 190, 115, '1B', 0.284, 'Cuba', 2),
    ('Kevin', 'Kiermaier', '1990-04-22', 185, 95, 'OF', 0.228, 'USA', 3),
    ('Nolan', 'Arenado', '1991-04-16', 188, 97, '3B', 0.315, 'USA', 4),
    ('Mike', 'Trout', '1991-08-07', 188, 106, 'OF', 0.291, 'USA', 5),
    ('Aaron', 'Judge', '1992-04-26', 201, 127, 'OF', 0.272, 'USA', 6),
    ('Giancarlo', 'Stanton', '1989-11-08', 198, 111, 'OF', 0.288, 'USA', 6),
    ('Joey', 'Votto', '1983-09-10', 188, 99, '1B', 0.261, 'Canada', 8);
```

(3B, SS, 2B, 1B, etc. being the positions)

Here is some sample data for the `Team` table.

```
INSERT INTO team
VALUES
    ('Toronto Blue Jays', 'Toronto', 'ON', 'Canada', 'Charlie Montoyo', 'AL', 'Rogers Centre'),
    ('Chicago White Sox', 'Chicago', 'IL', 'USA', 'Rick Renteria', 'AL', 'Guaranteed Rate Field'),
    ('Tampa Bay Rays', 'Tampa Bay', 'FL', 'USA', 'Kevin Cash', 'AL', 'Tropicana Field'),
    ('Colorado Rockies', 'Denver', 'CO', 'USA', 'Bud Black', 'NL', 'Coors Field'),
    ('Los Angeles Angels', 'Anaheim', 'CA', 'USA', 'Joe Maddon', 'AL', 'Angel Stadium of Anaheim'),
    ('New York Yankees', 'New York', 'NY', 'USA', 'Aaron Boone', 'AL', 'Yankee Stadium'),
    ('Pittsburgh Pirates', 'Pittsburgh', 'PA', 'USA', 'Derek Shelton', 'NL', 'PNC Park'),
    ('Cincinnati Reds', 'Cincinnati', 'OH', 'USA', 'David Bell', 'NL', 'Great American Ball Park');
```

**My expected query result should be 2.**

So that means that 2 athletes voted for someone who plays the same position as themselves.

I was thinking the query's top half should be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.athleteId) 
FROM athlete AS v
JOIN athlete AS a ON v.athleteID = a.votesforId
```

I am not sure what the `WHERE` would be.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see athlete.votesForId in your tables (but it's in your query). Your title says you want to base your query on athletePosition, but you're not using that in your query.

Comment: @DaleK Do I just type out the tables? I tried to search what you meant by using DDL for a table but got kind of confused

Comment: where do you keep the votes?

Comment: @eshirvana sorry for that, just updated the table. I forgot that in my original I used the `UPDATE` statement to add in 'votesForId'

Comment: @DaleK I think I edited everything to how it is supposed to be now

Comment: And your insert statement doesn't work, probably because you haven't listed your columns in your insert statement (best practice). You really need to ensure you have a working [mre] before posting else you waste peoples time.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for always being helpful, I'm still trying to learn how to properly create questions on the site. The expected result should be 2, like this exactly: https://i.imgur.com/9NPtFUj.png , so it means that 2 athletes voted for a someone who plays the same position as himself

Comment: With regard to my previous comment about ensuring you have a working [mre], that may mean removing the identify column, because you are referencing id's in your sample data that may or may not match the auto-generated id's for someone else. Instead just use an int column and include the actual id as part of the sample data.

Comment: And as for the minimal part of the [mre] you don't need to give us table definitions of tables which are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this using an inner join with the same table. In the proposed solution, I aliased one `voter` to represent those who casted votes and the other `nominated` for those who votes were cast for. The inner join was done  on the `athletePosition` on both table aliases  and `voter.votesForId= nominated.athleteId` before finding the total records.

It was difficult to replicate with the shared schema and data however, I believe the StackOverflow community has shared some valuable insights on how to proceed with these in the comments.

I have shared a db-fiddle that replicates your problem and the proposed solution.

#### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE award(
    awardId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    awardName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    awardSponsor VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT pk_award_awardId PRIMARY KEY (awardId)
);   

CREATE TABLE team(
    teamId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    teamName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    teamCity VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    teamState CHAR(2),
    teamCountry VARCHAR(6),
    teamManager VARCHAR(50),
    teamLeague CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    teamStadium VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT pk_team_teamId PRIMARY KEY (teamId)
);
 
CREATE TABLE athlete(
    athleteId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    athleteFirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    athleteLastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    athleteDateOfBirth DATE,
    athleteHeight SMALLINT,
    athleteWeight TINYINT,
    athletePosition CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    athleteBattingAvg DECIMAL(4, 3) DEFAULT 0.000,
    athleteNationality VARCHAR(30),
    votesForId INT,
    teamId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_athlete_athleteId PRIMARY KEY (athleteId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_athlete_team FOREIGN KEY(teamId) REFERENCES team (teamId)
);

CREATE TABLE winner(
    winnerId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    winnerYear INT NOT NULL,
    athleteId INT NOT NULL,
    awardId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_winner_winnerId PRIMARY KEY (winnerId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_winner_athlete FOREIGN KEY (athleteId) REFERENCES athlete (athleteId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_winner_award FOREIGN KEY (awardId) REFERENCES award (awardId)
);
GO

INSERT INTO team
VALUES
    ('Toronto Blue Jays', 'Toronto', 'ON', 'Canada', 'Charlie Montoyo', 'AL', 'Rogers Centre'),
    ('Chicago White Sox', 'Chicago', 'IL', 'USA', 'Rick Renteria', 'AL', 'Guaranteed Rate Field'),
    ('Tampa Bay Rays', 'Tampa Bay', 'FL', 'USA', 'Kevin Cash', 'AL', 'Tropicana Field'),
    ('Colorado Rockies', 'Denver', 'CO', 'USA', 'Bud Black', 'NL', 'Coors Field'),
    ('Los Angeles Angels', 'Anaheim', 'CA', 'USA', 'Joe Maddon', 'AL', 'Angel Stadium of Anaheim'),
    ('New York Yankees', 'New York', 'NY', 'USA', 'Aaron Boone', 'AL', 'Yankee Stadium'),
    ('Pittsburgh Pirates', 'Pittsburgh', 'PA', 'USA', 'Derek Shelton', 'NL', 'PNC Park'),
    ('Cincinnati Reds', 'Cincinnati', 'OH', 'USA', 'David Bell', 'NL', 'Great American Ball Park');

 INSERT INTO athlete (
    athleteFirstName ,
    athleteLastName ,
    athleteDateOfBirth,
    athleteHeight,
    athleteWeight,
    athletePosition,
    athleteBattingAvg,
    athleteNationality,
    teamId,
    votesForId
 )
VALUES 
    ('Vladimir', 'Guererro Jr.', '1999-03-16', 188, 113, '3B', 0.272, 'Canada', 1,2),
    ('Bo', 'Bichette', '1998-03-05', 183, 83, 'SS', 0.311, 'USA', 1,1),
    ('Cavan', 'Biggio', '1995-04-11', 188, 90, '2B', 0.234, 'USA', 1,3),
    ('Travis', 'Shaw', '1990-04-16', 193, 104, '1B', 0.157, 'USA', 1,1),
    ('Danny', 'Jansen', '1995-04-15', 188, 104, 'C', 0.207, 'USA', 1,2),
    ('Randal', 'Grichuk', '1991-08-13', 188, 96, 'OF', 0.232, 'USA', 1,3),
    ('Teoscar', 'Hernandez', '1992-10-15', 188, 92, 'OF', 0.230, 'Dominican Republic', 1,2),
    ('Tim', 'Anderson', '1993-06-23', 185, 83, 'SS', 0.335, 'USA', 2,1),
    ('Jose', 'Abreu', '1987-01-29', 190, 115, '1B', 0.284, 'Cuba', 2,1),
    ('Kevin', 'Kiermaier', '1990-04-22', 185, 95, 'OF', 0.228, 'USA', 3,1),
    ('Nolan', 'Arenado', '1991-04-16', 188, 97, '3B', 0.315, 'USA', 4,1),
    ('Mike', 'Trout', '1991-08-07', 188, 106, 'OF', 0.291, 'USA', 5,1),
    ('Aaron', 'Judge', '1992-04-26', 201, 127, 'OF', 0.272, 'USA', 6,1),
    ('Giancarlo', 'Stanton', '1989-11-08', 198, 111, 'OF', 0.288, 'USA', 6,1),
    ('Joey', 'Votto', '1983-09-10', 188, 99, '1B', 0.261, 'Canada', 8,1);
```

#### Proposed Solution

```
SELECT
   SUM(1) as num_votes
FROM
    athlete voter
INNER JOIN
    athlete nominated ON voter.votesForId = nominated.athleteId AND
                         voter.athletePosition = nominated.athletePosition
```

Returns:

| num_votes |
| --- |
| 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=467edbc888e84d8f17c110aa58ee1c4c)*

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you just want to test whether each player voted for someone else who plays in the same position as them, and them sum it. But do you want count someone who votes for themselves? As in your first player?

```
with cte as (
    select case when exists (select 1 from athlete A1 where A1.athleteId = A.votesForId and A1.athletePosition = A.athletePosition) then 1 else 0 end CountThisPlayer
    from athlete A
)
select sum(CountThisPlayer) NumberPlayedVotedForSamePosition
from cte;
```

Note: If your table is called `athlete`, I highly recommend not prefixing all your column names with the table name, that just leads to a lot of unnecessary typing e.g. just use `firstName` not `athleteFirstName`.

Note: Its best practice to list the columns you are inserting into as part of your `insert` statement.